# My screensave somehow got disabled in services.msc. Need to enable it

Tags: windows, services, screensaver

Screen saver was running fine in Win10 Home. It stopped running after no activity. I have checked all settings, they have no changed. I tried different screensavers, I checked registry entries, they are correct. I then did ctrl-alt-del and services showed it was disabled. I have gone to services.msc but cannot find that service listed because I do not know what the service is called.  Please help.

Comment: Try the Screen Saver fixes here:  https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-fix-windows-10-screensaver-not-working

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1: accessing the .cpl file directly

Try running this from an elevated command prompt:

```
control desk.cpl,screensaver,@screensaver
```

Note that if you run something as administrator under UAC, you may be setting another user's screen saver setting.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/344153/598567)

## Method 2: Turn On / Off Screen Saver Using Group Policy

1. Press Windows key + R and type **gpedit.msc** and hit Enter. This will open the [Local Group Policy Editor](https://www.top-password.com/blog/open-local-group-policy-editor-in-windows-10/)

[image]

2. Navigate to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization. Double-click on the policy labeled "Enable screen saver".

[image]

3. Set it to **Disabled** if you want to turn off screen saver. After disabling, [all the screen saver settings options will be greyed out](https://www.top-password.com/blog/fix-screen-saver-settings-greyed-out-in-windows/). If you want to turn on screen saver later, you need to set that option to **Enabled**.

[image]

4. Click OK and reboot your computer for the changes to take effect.

[SOURCE](https://www.top-password.com/blog/turn-on-or-off-screen-saver-in-windows-10-8-7/)